# Hamiltonian path, add edges and vertices, does the hamiltonian path still exists?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If I have a connected graph G that contains a hamiltonian path and the number of vertices are |V|>=2, if i extend the graph G on an edge with two vertices to make a square for example:

I have an edge and two vertices in a graph that contains a hamiltonian path like this (in a larger graph):
o---o

And if I extend it with three edges and two vertices:
o---o
| . . |
o---o

(ignore the dots)

Will it still (in all cases) contain a hamiltonian path (with the two vertices and three edges that i added to it included)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean a Hamiltonian path, or a Hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: Hamiltonian path. I have trouble finding a graph with a hamiltonian path where this does not apply and the new graph still contains a hamiltonian path (where the new vertices are included).

Comment: It works if your Hamiltonian path in the old graph uses that particular edge. Then the new vertices act just like that edge. Otherwise you have a problem though.

Comment: If the two vertices that belongs to that specific edge have even degrees, will it work then (even if the hamiltonian path in the old graph doesn't use that particular edge)?

Answer (score 2):

Consider what would happen if you had five vertices labeled $1,2,3,4,5$, with an edge between $n$ and $n+1$ for $1\leq n\leq4$, as well as one edge from $2$ to $4$. There is only one Hamiltonian path, and that's $12345$ (or its reverse). Now see what happens if you build your square on the $24$ edge.

Comment: I realized now that my statement does not hold. Needed an example to prove me wrong. Many thanks!